# String intersection (find video with matching tags) in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a Postgres database with videos that have tags. The tags are stored alphabetically in a semicolon delimited list. I want to be able to query the database with a list of tags and return the video with the highest match.

I've looked at using `regexp_match`, `~`, and others.

The best I've come up with thus far is a mediocre heuristic that searches for tags with regex i.e.

```
SELECT FROM videos WHERE tags ~ 'kitten.*laser'
```

Bonus (imo) that this will also match tags like `fat-kitten` or `big-laser`

but the problem here is that if a video is missing one of those tags than I won't get that in my result, and if a user picks too many tags than they won't see any videos. To remedy that I started iterating for the number of videos I want and popping off the less relevant tags, but that's probabilistic at best and a disaster at worst.

What I'm looking for is some kind of Postgres query where I can pass in a regex and find the results from `videos` with the largest intersection.

For example, let's pretend we're querying from the following data:

```
cat;disaster;mouse
kitten;mouse;piano
cat;mouse;keyboard
```

An optimal query for the tags `cat, mouse, keyboard` would return rows in the following order

```
cat;mouse;keyboard
cat;disaster;mouse
kitten;mouse;piano
```

because the 1st row contains 3 matches, the next row contains 2 matches, and the last row contains one match.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected out-put ?

Comment: are you hard set on using postgresql? this is task for which a full text search capable db would be much more suitable than a relational one...

Comment: PostgreSQL has full text search (finally!  See chapter 12 of the manual).  OP could use it, but that's can of a bad solution, since he's not searching text, he's searching tags.  The reason it's text is because /it is stored inappropriately/...

Comment: @BadZen why is `text` storage not appropriate? Many times the tag data exceeds VARCHAR 255

Comment: Try storing your tags in a normalized table (TAG text, TAG_ID int pkey), and using a many-many mapping table to map videos to tags.  This is the standard, best way to do this in relational paradigm.   You could then write SQL which counts number of tag matches, or even do things like add a weight to tag match relation and sum/multiply or use an SP which returns some specialized fitness function...

Comment: @yurib Pg has had in-core fulltext since 8.3 and an extension for the same for longer. I'm not sure where you're getting the idea it doesn't have fulltext search.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Come on, you have to admit (I'm one of those "WHY ARE YOU USING MYSQL" guys) that it was a sore spot for awhile...  not hard to see why people might have the impression that it didn't still...   heck I still think of mysql as not supporting enforced referential integrity.  remember that? ;)

Comment: You might want to read this: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html it compares various ways to store tags in Postgres

Answer (score 2):

To find the rows with the tags, you can use Postgres' array handling which might be more efficient that regular expressions.

```
select *
from tag
where string_to_array(tags, ';') && array['cat', 'mouse', 'keyboard'];
```

the `&&` means overlaps - if the left and the right hand side have at least one element in common the row will be returned. Unfortunately there is no "intersect" operator for arrays which would give you the ability to rank the results. It will however not match `fat-cat`

The above could be improved by creating a GiST index on the `tags` column because the `&&` operator can use such an index (but GiST indexes are more expensive to build than regular B-Tree indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Tags are a classic many-many thing.  Would it be possible to move your tags into their own table? You'd also need a join table that has the links between tags and videos. Apologies if you by passed this approach for a reason, but I thought I'd throw it out there since it's fairly well traveled.

Comment: Yes.  What JRS says.  Do it that way. =)

Comment: While tags are a classic many-many thing, being able to search multiple tags together across thousands of videos with thousands of tags will NOT scale

Comment: Thousands cross thousands?   Heh.  You're good with this approach, trust me.

Comment: (you'd need more specialized data algorithms & parallel processing the in the billions cross billions range)

Comment: Vs regexing a bunch of strings.  I'd do a little testing to confirm.

Comment: To be more concrete - JRS is saying that regex is /really expensive/ compared to what we are proposing as an alternative.   And you should try it both ways to be sure.   (I'd put 8:1 money odds regex is slooooow comparatively in situ in your system)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table:

```
create table tag (tags text);
insert into tag values
('cat;disaster;mouse'),
('kitten;mouse;piano'),
('cat;mouse;keyboard');
```

given query sorts results according to tag matches count:

```
select 
  tags
from tag
order by 
  (select 
    sum(case t.tag in ('cat', 'mouse', 'keyboard') when true then 1 else 0 end) as match 
  from regexp_split_to_table(tags, ';') as t(tag) ) 
desc;
```

Unluckily

> Bonus (imo) that this will also match tags like fat-kitten or
>   big-laser

bonus had gone, but it's also possible to rewrite query a bit to achieve it.